# Android Fragment show ProgressDialog crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one `Activity` and lots of `Fragment`s. I switched these fragments with `hide` & `show`. At first time everything is ok, but When I exited the app and restarted the app crashed.

Here is the exception message:

```
[ 05-10 10:47:12.561 15134:15134 E/         ]
                  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@30940158 is not valid; is your activity running?
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:606)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:311)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)
                      at ruiming.com.medicalmanagement.view.MainActivity.showProgressDialog(MainActivity.java:447)
                      at ruiming.com.medicalmanagement.view.PatientsCases.loadList(PatientsCases.java:106)
                      at ruiming.com.medicalmanagement.view.PatientsCases.onViewCreated(PatientsCases.java:92)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1069)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5689)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This are `progressDialog`'s `show` and `hide` functions:

```
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static void showProgressDialog(Activity mActivity) {
    if(progressDialog == null){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Please wait", "Loading...", true, false);
    }
    if(!mActivity.isFinishing() && !progressDialog.isShowing()){
        progressDialog.show();
    }      
}

public static void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

These functions were in the Activity.

This is my fragment's code:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.showProgressDialog(getActivity());
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mList = MyJDBCUtil.getPrAcupuntrueCode(getActivity());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventBean.PrDiagonsisEvent("3"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN, priority = 0, sticky = false)
    public void refreshList(EventBean.PrDiagonsisEvent pr) {
        if (pr.getMsg().equals("3")) {
            adapter = new TreatmentAdapter(getActivity());
            lvTreatmentList.setAdapter(adapter);
            MainActivity.hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Any suggestions please？

Comment: Can you post your entire logcat? If the error occurs in the hideProgressDialog method, the refreshList method is probably being called after the activity is no longer visible. Also, avoid at all keeping a static reference for any window class, you are causing a big memory leak, because the ProgressDialog will have a reference to the activity.

Comment: @jonathanrz I post entire logcat. The error occurs in the showProgressDialog. Error location is progressDialog.show(). I don't understand what happen in the reference . Can you give me some suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In your `showProgressDialog()` your are calling :

```
progressDialog.show();
```

two times..

The error occurs when you are showing the `dialog` for a context that no longer exists.

so modify your code to..

```
 public static void showProgressDialog(Activity mActivity) {
    if((progressDialog == null) && (!mActivity.isFinishing())){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Please wait", "Loading...", true, false);
    }
    if(!mActivity.isFinishing() && !progressDialog.isShowing()){
        progressDialog.show();
    }      
}
```